# Get paypal payment confirmation for next time

Tags: android

I integrated pay pal sdk in my app and I want that if any user pay with device and Then he/she deleted app from his/her device. After that next time if they install app again then how we get that user already pay money for this app.

Note : we are not using web services and share preference. I want that any thing available in pay pal if you know then please reply.

thank you.

Comment: please help me. I had stuck now.